# django email html is not rendering in some cases

Tags: python, django, email, postfix-mta

I am using django 1.3.1 with postfix sending html emails there is an issue same code is sending 20% emails as plain text and 80% is sending as html.

I searched in google for any reported issue but no one reported anything.

Thanks,

Comment: is the problem at the server side?  i mean if you print the email being sent out, do you see plain text or html ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not a customer client problem, some clients configured do not accept the HTML. In other words, how do you get these numbers: 80% and 20%? Please give some other info.

Comment: if you are viewing in some clients which do not support html, you will see text output

Comment: I am bcc and that is the issue only with edited registration profile another three apps are using the same code and is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the MIME type of the body parameter in an EmailMessage is "text/plain".if you are confident that your recipients can handle an alternative content type, you can use the content_subtype attribute on the EmailMessage class to change the main content type.

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```

Comment: I am sending the html from four apps only registration app (edited with same code as the others) is sending 80% html and 20%text.